# RSA Encryption(SecItem.h), PKCSPadding is it available only in Iphone Device?

Tags: iphone

Can i able to compile and test RSA encryption methods available in Security Framework in simulator or i should buy developer license to enable that framework.

is it only available on device with developer license enabled?
currently i am getting lot of missing attributes while compiling in simulator , but those attributes are available in SecItem.h ,  but i cannot find that in security framework in SDK simulator mode

any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simulator and device should be the same, they are for me.  Check to the paths to the SecItem.h files you are using, the iPhone header is not the same as the Mac OS header.